# Oracle Forms 6i on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, windows

Given I have a system of Oracle Forms 6i (legacy software), how could I make it work on Windows 7. We have serious problems with apps like `PLUS80.exe` crashing ("Oracle SQL*Plus has stopped working").

Is it possible at all? We also consider downgrading to XP if problems persist..

Answer (score 5):

Virtulization is an option if it won't work on Windows 7.

Comment: That seems to be the recommendation of folk on OTN: [thread1](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1010618&tstart=7545), [thread2](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1050882). XP Mode for example

Answer (score 2):

We have successfully deployed Oracle Forms 6i on Windows 7 in both 32-bit and 64-bit varieties without virtualization. We apply Patchset 13, and everything appears to behave correctly. Our system (we are a software vendor) is being used in production at several businesses without any major problems. I recommend you setup a pilot computer to test to make sure that your particular legacy app will work. If you do find problems, you can always install the legacy application in [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx). We have not tried it on Windows 8.

Comment: I realize you probably already took care of your issue considering you posted the question a year ago, but I'm just trying to help build this community since it seems to be so much smaller than some of the others in the StackExchange network.

Comment: Now I'm a little stuck here about which answer to accept. :-) We actually went with a second XP-PC that time. However I really appreciate your support! When was Patchset 13 released?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. For some reason, info on anything to do with Forms and Reports 6i is extremely hard to come by even from a historical perspective. It is the patchset to make it compatible with Windows XP, so it was probably released sometime in '02 or '03.